# Is it possible to get an output from a hidden adaptive card in an action set?

Tags: power-automate, adaptive-cards

I have an adaptive card going to a user in Teams. The card includes a list of values for a user to review and Submit if they're good. If a value needs to be changed, there's an Edit button. The Edit button will Action.ShowCard. A portion of that code is below.

```
    {
        "type": "ActionSet",
        "actions": [
            {
                "type": "Action.ShowCard",
                "title": "Edit Information ✏️",
                "card": {
                    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
                    "body": [
                        {
```

It seems I'm not getting an output from this adaptive card in Power Automate (screenshot included). I need the output of this card to fill in the values of the following action to Update an item in SPO. The value I'm currently using is @{body('Post_adaptive_card_and_wait_for_a_response_3')?['data']?['client']}.

**Is it possible to extract data out of the embedded adaptive card?**

[Post Adaptive Card And Wait For Response - OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwNNA.jpg)

[I initially posted in the Power Automate Community here where you can find more screenshots.](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Is-an-Input-Text-within-an-ActionSet-gt-Action-ShowCard-usable/td-p/1368298)